# how to web scrape from a graph data with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to web scrape data from this internet page especially the graph of historical data ([Here](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Historique/19801)).
First I would like to select the button which indicates the longest data ([image: Here] and then get the data from the graph ([Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl8Y6.jpg))

Maybe someone can help me with how to proceed. and more than that how can we do where and how to find the data?

I don't know where to find the data when I inspect the website.

Comment: This is flat-out the wrong approach, and it makes me think you haven't tried very hard.  This fund has the identifier LU0119110996 (and ALL funds have identifers).  If you Google "LU0119110996 history". you'll find any number of places where you can download the data behind this chart.  You don't have to go through hackery to try to read a bitmap and extract what would only be an approximation.

Comment: @Tim, You are right, I can get this information from other sites.  But from this site I can get others funds very easily if I can manage what I wanted to do (get the data from the graph). The historical price is not available on every site for every funds that's why I would like to do that.

Comment: OK, but think about the limitations of scraping a graph.  The Y axis has about 1 pixel per Euro, so the prices will all be approximations, and each year spans about 150 pixels, so you can't get any more than every other day.  You'll get at best a bad guess.  This is just the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Historique/19801"

api_url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetChartHisto_Historique?currency=EUR"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
mn = soup.select_one("#date-min-produit")["value"]
mx = soup.select_one("#date-max-produit")["value"]
prod_id = soup.select_one('#produit-identifier')['value']

id_, type_, classe_ = prod_id.split('_')

query = [
    {
        "ID": int(id_),
        "Nom": soup.h1.strong.text.strip(),
        "Type": int(type_),
        "Color": "#0A50A1",
        "FinancialItem": {
            "ID_Produit": int(id_),
            "cTypeFinancialItem": int(type_),
            "cClasseFinancialItem": int(classe_),
            "nModeCalcul": 0,
        },
    }
]

data = {
    "ID_Produit": id_,
    "jsonListeCourbes": json.dumps(query),
    "sDtStart": mn,
    "sDtEnd": mx,
}

data = requests.post(api_url, data=data).json()
graph = json.loads(data['graph'])
df = pd.DataFrame(graph['dataProvider'])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
            x     y_0
0  2004-10-27  100.00
1  2004-10-28  100.00
2  2004-10-29  100.54
3  2004-10-30  100.54
4  2004-10-31  100.54
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Is it possible to get the name of the fund from the web site ???Could you please explain a little bit your code ???  Just to understand what you did.

Comment: @jacques When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and change the history to "All history", you will see Ajax request the page is doing. This script simulates this request.